# python write to file is breaking

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am writing python script to fetch mysql db rows and copy to excel file

The Code I am trying on 2.7.6 :

```
from __future__ import print_function
import MySQLdb as mdb

conn = mdb.connect("localhost","username","passwd","db")
table = open("table.csv" , 'w')
with conn:    
    query = "SELECT NAME FROM mytable WHERE H_ID= 5 ORDER BY NAME;"        
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    for item in range(cursor.rowcount):            
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        print(row[0],file=table)
```

If I execute that query in mysql means I will get 446 rows and while printing on python shell [ idle ] also I will get proper result , But when I try to copy the output to file **I am able to see only 341 rows. What may be the problem.?**

Comment: `I try to copy the output to file` means to `table.csv`?

Comment: Yes copy the output to table.csv file , Any mistake in that ?

Comment: instead of `for item in range(cursor.rowcount): ` please try `item in cursor:` this might be help. [fetchone help] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "when I try to copy the output to file" ? What are you doing exactly?

Comment: @Lafada: Yes , Tried that one too , No Luck

Comment: @ReutSharabani : If I just print row[0] it will display output in python shell instead I am printing to file using `print(row[0],file=table)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Don't know what exactly the problem, But It got resolved when I remove **with** keyword and closing the file manually ,

Below code works properly.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import MySQLdb as mdb

conn = mdb.connect("localhost","username","passwd","db")
table = open("table.csv" , 'w')
query = "SELECT NAME FROM mytable WHERE H_ID= 5 ORDER BY NAME;"        
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
for item in range(cursor.rowcount):            
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print(row[0],file=table)
table.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the doc of Python connector for `cursor.rowcount`:

> For nonbuffered cursors, the row count cannot be known before the rows have been  fetched. In this case, the number of rows is -1 immediately after query > execution and is incremented as rows are fetched.

Therefore, the block for `for item in range(cursor.rowcount):` will not be executed.

Try:

```
for row in cursor:
    print(row[0], file=table)
```